# Is it possible to send long array as a post request using axios in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, antd

I want to send very big array as a post request to backend but i didn't want send it simultaneously as an array, instead i want send it consecutively and show message every time one `id` is send. I am using `ant design` and `axios` for send data to Backend

```
addToCart(selectedRowKeys)
    .then(res => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setIsAddToCartLoading(false)
            setIsCartModelView(false);
            message.success('Product add to cart successfully')
        }, 2000);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        setIsAddToCartLoading(false)
        message.error('Failed process action!')
    })
```

where `selectedRowKeys = [253, 564, 545, 521, 454, 111, 541]`

I am using this formula but it send all the array value simultaneously but i want when `253` as `post` request than send a message like `message.success('Product add to cart successfully')` and then same to others array value as consecutively.

my `addToCart` post request, it take array and string both.

```
axios.post(`agent/store-account/add-to-cart/${id}`)
```

My question is how i can send my post request consecutively and show message in front-end user for better experience?

Comment: Do you want to send multiple requests instead of one and expect better performance?

Comment: yes but i have an array only ```selectedRowKeys = [253, 564, 545, 521, 454, 111, 541]```

Comment: One large request is usually faster than multiple small requests.

Comment: I know but my user demands for one by one request but only on click

Comment: Loop over the array elements and send requests one by one. `axios.post` returns a promise. You can await it.

Comment: can you help me with ```code``` i am try to use array but somehow it is not working

Comment: `for (const id of selectedRowKeys) { await axios.post(\`agent/store-account/add-to-cart/${id}\`) }`